# Real Time push messages

Tags: c#, performance, push-notification, real-time

I am trying to push around 100 XML messages per second to 3rd party web client.

The pushing works with HTTP POST at the moment.

I was wondering what would be a good way to do it?

Are there any real time pushers for C#?

Answer (score 1):

WebSync is also a good solution and very easy to set up. It has a similar publisher/subscriber model as mentioned in one of the other answers.

http://www.frozenmountain.com/websync/